# Почему выдаёт ошибку и как её исправить?

Tags: c++, cmake

Почему выдаёт ошибку и как её исправить?

Ошибка:

> In file included from C:\Users\Kirill
>   Pukhov\CLion\untitled\data.h:5:0, from C:\Users\Kirill
>   Pukhov\CLion\untitled\main.cpp:2: C:\Users\Kirill
>   Pukhov\CLion\untitled\subjects.h: In function 'void newSubject()':
>   C:\Users\Kirill Pukhov\CLion\untitled\subjects.h:42:17: error:
>   'saveData' was not declared in this scope saveData(sub); ^
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1

*CMakeList.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(untitled)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(untitled main.cpp subjects.h data.h)
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include "data.h"
#include "subjects.h"

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    std::cout << "Нажмите 1, что-бы загрузить список предметов \n";
    std::cout << "Нажмите 2, что-бы добавить предмет в список \n";
    std::cout << "Нажмите 3, что-бы закрыть приложение \n";

    switch(getch()) {
        case '1':
            break;
        case '2':
            newSubject();
            break;
        case '3':
            break;
        default :
            std::cout << "Ошибка \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*data.h*

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_DATA_H
#define UNTITLED_DATA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "subjects.h"

void loadData(subject sub) { // Считывание данных из файла
    std::ifstream fin(sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data");
    if(!fin.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Warning of opening the file: " + sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data";
    } else {
        fin.read((char*)&sub, sizeof(sub));
    }
    fin.close();
}

void saveData(subject sub) { // Запись данных в файл
    std::ofstream fout(sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data");
    if(!fout.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Warning of opening the file: " + sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data";
    } else {
        fout.write((char*)&sub, sizeof(sub));
    }
    fout.close();
}

#endif //UNTITLED_DATA_H
```

*subjects.h*

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_SUBJECTS_H
#define UNTITLED_SUBJECTS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "data.h"

class subject {
public:
    subject(std::string nameOfSubject) { // Конструктор
        this->nameOfSubject = nameOfSubject;
    }

    ~subject() { // Деконструктор

    }

    void takeMarks(std::vector<int> marks) { // Вывести оценки
        for(auto &iter : marks) {
            std::cout << iter << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    int takeAverageNum(std::vector<int> marks) { // Получить среднее арефметическое
        int sum = 0;
        for(int &mark : marks) {
            sum += mark;
        }
        return (sum / (marks.size() + 1));
    }

    std::string takeNameOfSubject() { // Получить имя предмета
        return nameOfSubject;
    }
private:
    std::string nameOfSubject; // Имя предмета
};

void newSubject() { // Создание нового предмета
    std::string nameOfSubject;
    std::getline(std::cin, nameOfSubject);
    subject sub(nameOfSubject);
    saveData(sub);
}

#endif //UNTITLED_SUBJECTS_H
```

Comment: Когда ты нажимаешь 1 что должно происходить? std::cout << "Нажмите 1, что-бы загрузить список предметов \n"; std::cout << "Нажмите 2, что-бы добавить предмет в список \n"; std::cout << "Нажмите 3, что-бы закрыть приложение \n"; switch(getch()) { case '1': break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Краткий ответ.** Перенесите тела функций в cpp файлы.

**Длинный ответ.** Для начала посмотрим, что делает `#include` - а он просто вставляет содержимое файла. Потом следующая часть препроцессора - исключение текста (да, еще текста, а не кода) по условиям (`#ifdef` и коллеги). Если Вы аккуратно все это сделаете (или попросите gcc  с параметром `-E`), то увидите, что тело и объявление функции SaveData находится ниже, чем использование в subjects.h. А компилятор не умеет заглядывать вниз.

Когда же все тела функций будут вынесены, то в заголовочных файлах будет только обявление функций и все станет хорошо.

Но можно сделать "*хак ногой*" (никогда не делайте так в реальном проекте, только в учебных целях).

Перед функцией `newSubject` добавить одну строку с объявлением сигнатуры функции

```
void saveData(subject sub);
```

и теперь компилятор будет счастлив. Но, возможно, нужно будет и ряд других функций попереносить.

**P.S.** Покажу на примере data.h

data.h

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_DATA_H
#define UNTITLED_DATA_H

#include "subjects.h"

// Считывание данных из файла
void loadData(subject sub);

// Запись данных в файл
void saveData(subject sub);

#endif //UNTITLED_DATA_H
```

data.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "data.h"
#include "subjects.h"

void loadData(subject sub) { // Считывание данных из файла
    std::ifstream fin(sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data");
    if(!fin.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Warning of opening the file: " + sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data";
    } else {
        fin.read((char*)&sub, sizeof(sub));
    }
    fin.close();
}

void saveData(subject sub) { // Запись данных в файл
    std::ofstream fout(sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data");
    if(!fout.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Warning of opening the file: " + sub.takeNameOfSubject() + ".data";
    } else {
        fout.write((char*)&sub, sizeof(sub));
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: Я перенес тела функций в cpp файл, а что писать в h файле?